# MySqlDataReader.GetBytes

Tags: c#, mysql, .net

I have been have a bit of an issue with `MySqlDataReader.GetBytes`, and referencing the column ordinal.

Table structure:

```
ID - Primary, int, not null, auto_increment
TNode - , not null
Packet - longblob
Timestamp - timestamp
```

If I run the following query:

```sql
SELECT * FROM table WHERE TNode = 2;
```

And attempt to get the size of the longblob using the following method:

```
while (reader.Read()) 
{
     long l = reader.GetBytes(2,0,null,0,0);
}
```

I will receive the following error:

> GetBytes can only be called on binary or guid columns

Which, column index 2 is.  Even if I iterate through all of the columns, as expected, I receive the same error.  But if I run the following query:

```sql
SELECT Packet, ID, Timestamp FROM table WHERE TNode = 2;
```

Followed by:

```
while (reader.Read()) 
{
     long l = reader.GetBytes(0, 0, null, 0, 0);
}
```

No problems.  I am able to get the length of the longblob, and do what I need to do with it.

Any ideas as to why it is not allowing me to use a non-zero column index?

Thank you.

Comment: try looking at the accepted answer here and do something like what's being done there.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11135245/what-length-parameter-should-i-pass-to-sqldatareader-getbytes

Comment: Badabing!  That was too damn easy.  Thank Kraze.

Comment: sometimes the easiest things are easily overlooked.. glad I could help

Comment: interesting, what if there are several BLOB columns returned by query? How then this would work long l = reader.GetBytes(0, 0, null, 0, 0);?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about MySQL, but in SQL Server SELECT * might not return the columns in the order you expect. It might NOT be column 2. In fact, if you change the table and continue to use SELECT * you might introduce a hard-to-find bug. I'd suggest specifying the columns as you did in your test.

Comment: Yeah, I get that.  Its weird though, even if the wild card select doesn't return the columns in the expected order, prior to running a GetBytes, if I iterate through the columns and get the index of the Packet column, it still fails if the index greater than 0.