# Webservice returning byte array

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, web-services, webmethod

I have a webservice that gets a list of byte[] from the db. I want to be able to return all the values. How do I return a byte[].

```
 [WebMethod]
        public List<fgrTemplate> StudentVerifications()
         {
            List<fgrTemplate> listOfFgrTemp = new List<fgrTemplate>();
            cn.Open();
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("SELECT Template FROM tblFingerprint", cn);
            SqlDataReader sr = com.ExecuteReader();
            while (sr.Read())
            {
                fgrTemplate fingerprint = new fgrTemplate()
                {
                    ID = sr.GetInt32(0),
                    StudentID = sr.GetInt32(1),
                    Description = sr.GetString(2)
                    Template = sr.GetByte??
                };
 listOfFgrTemp.Add(fingerprint);
  }

            cn.Close();
            return listOfFgrTemp;

        }
```

Comment: What is the data type in SQL server for your byte array?

Comment: data type for template is image

Comment: you not considered `sr.getBytes()`?

Comment: The following might actually help as it gives example code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11135245/what-length-parameter-should-i-pass-to-sqldatareader-getbytes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
Template = (byte[])sr[3];
```

OR

```
Template = (byte[])sr["Template"];
```

Comment: thanks this worked but when i tried to run my application m_storedtemplate is returning null value. fgrTemplate[] m_StoredTemplate = verify.StudentVerifications();